Standard errors around predictions from Dirichlet regression
I am fitting a Dirichlet regression in R, with the DirichletReg package (version 0.7-1). In short, the Dirichlet regression extends the beta regression to C categories: bounded responses (0, 1) across more than 2 categories. This regression comes in two parametrizations: common (a separate model is fitted to each of the C categories) vs alternative (a separate model is fitted to C-1 categories, and precision is modelled separately). Each model can use a different set of explanatory variables, separated by pipes |.
The thing is that the predict() method lacks a se.fit option, and thus one can get predicted values, but not the uncertainty of the estimation.
Can anyone suggest how to obtain the standard errors? I have been able to obtain the predictions through matrix algebra, replicating the source code, but I am unsure about how to work out the standard errors. I have tried to work them out for the common parametrization with the model matrix and variance-covariance matrix, which works for other models with a single response. However, I don't have enough statistical background to be sure about whether they would be appropiate. I have no clue about how they could be obtained in the alternative parametrization.
Any help much appreciated!
library(DirichletReg)
#> Warning: package 'DirichletReg' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Loading required package: Formula

# Create response variable: how the proportion of three types of particle changes in sediment, with increasing depth
lake.data <- DR_data(ArcticLake[, 1:3])
#> Warning in DR_data(ArcticLake[, 1:3]): not all rows sum up to 1 => normalization
#> forced


# Alternative parametrization
dr.al <- DirichReg(lake.data ~ depth, ArcticLake, model = "alternative")
summary(dr.al)
#> Call:
#> DirichReg(formula = lake.data ~ depth, data = ArcticLake, model =
#> "alternative")
#> 
#> Standardized Residuals:
#>           Min       1Q   Median      3Q     Max
#> sand  -2.1727  -0.7195  -0.0995  0.6667  2.4301
#> silt  -1.2787  -0.4641  -0.0912  0.2062  1.6402
#> clay  -1.6192  -0.4955  -0.0453  0.7743  2.3654
#> 
#> MEAN MODELS:
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Coefficients for variable no. 1: sand
#> - variable omitted (reference category) -
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Coefficients for variable no. 2: silt
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -0.841774   0.217669  -3.867  0.00011 ***
#> depth        0.039272   0.005545   7.082 1.42e-12 ***
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Coefficients for variable no. 3: clay
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -2.275688   0.251782  -9.038   <2e-16 ***
#> depth        0.056236   0.005886   9.555   <2e-16 ***
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> PRECISION MODEL:
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)   2.6269     0.1623   16.19   <2e-16 ***
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Significance codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Log-likelihood: 77.74 on 5 df (42 BFGS + 1 NR Iterations)
#> AIC: -145.5, BIC: -137.2
#> Number of Observations: 39
#> Links: Logit (Means) and Log (Precision)
#> Parametrization: alternative
model.matrix(dr.al)
#> $X
#> $X[[1]]
#>    (Intercept) depth
#> 1            1  10.4
#> 2            1  11.7
#> 3            1  12.8
#> 4            1  13.0
#> 5            1  15.7
#> 6            1  16.3
#> 7            1  18.0
#> 8            1  18.7
#> 9            1  20.7
#> 10           1  22.1
#> 11           1  22.4
#> 12           1  24.4
#> 13           1  25.8
#> 14           1  32.5
#> 15           1  33.6
#> 16           1  36.8
#> 17           1  37.8
#> 18           1  36.9
#> 19           1  42.2
#> 20           1  47.0
#> 21           1  47.1
#> 22           1  48.4
#> 23           1  49.4
#> 24           1  49.5
#> 25           1  59.2
#> 26           1  60.1
#> 27           1  61.7
#> 28           1  62.4
#> 29           1  69.3
#> 30           1  73.6
#> 31           1  74.4
#> 32           1  78.5
#> 33           1  82.9
#> 34           1  87.7
#> 35           1  88.1
#> 36           1  90.4
#> 37           1  90.6
#> 38           1  97.7
#> 39           1 103.7
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> $X[[2]]
#>    (Intercept) depth
#> 1            1  10.4
#> 2            1  11.7
#> 3            1  12.8
#> 4            1  13.0
#> 5            1  15.7
#> 6            1  16.3
#> 7            1  18.0
#> 8            1  18.7
#> 9            1  20.7
#> 10           1  22.1
#> 11           1  22.4
#> 12           1  24.4
#> 13           1  25.8
#> 14           1  32.5
#> 15           1  33.6
#> 16           1  36.8
#> 17           1  37.8
#> 18           1  36.9
#> 19           1  42.2
#> 20           1  47.0
#> 21           1  47.1
#> 22           1  48.4
#> 23           1  49.4
#> 24           1  49.5
#> 25           1  59.2
#> 26           1  60.1
#> 27           1  61.7
#> 28           1  62.4
#> 29           1  69.3
#> 30           1  73.6
#> 31           1  74.4
#> 32           1  78.5
#> 33           1  82.9
#> 34           1  87.7
#> 35           1  88.1
#> 36           1  90.4
#> 37           1  90.6
#> 38           1  97.7
#> 39           1 103.7
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> $X[[3]]
#>    (Intercept) depth
#> 1            1  10.4
#> 2            1  11.7
#> 3            1  12.8
#> 4            1  13.0
#> 5            1  15.7
#> 6            1  16.3
#> 7            1  18.0
#> 8            1  18.7
#> 9            1  20.7
#> 10           1  22.1
#> 11           1  22.4
#> 12           1  24.4
#> 13           1  25.8
#> 14           1  32.5
#> 15           1  33.6
#> 16           1  36.8
#> 17           1  37.8
#> 18           1  36.9
#> 19           1  42.2
#> 20           1  47.0
#> 21           1  47.1
#> 22           1  48.4
#> 23           1  49.4
#> 24           1  49.5
#> 25           1  59.2
#> 26           1  60.1
#> 27           1  61.7
#> 28           1  62.4
#> 29           1  69.3
#> 30           1  73.6
#> 31           1  74.4
#> 32           1  78.5
#> 33           1  82.9
#> 34           1  87.7
#> 35           1  88.1
#> 36           1  90.4
#> 37           1  90.6
#> 38           1  97.7
#> 39           1 103.7
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> 
#> $Z
#>    (Intercept)
#> 1            1
#> 2            1
#> 3            1
#> 4            1
#> 5            1
#> 6            1
#> 7            1
#> 8            1
#> 9            1
#> 10           1
#> 11           1
#> 12           1
#> 13           1
#> 14           1
#> 15           1
#> 16           1
#> 17           1
#> 18           1
#> 19           1
#> 20           1
#> 21           1
#> 22           1
#> 23           1
#> 24           1
#> 25           1
#> 26           1
#> 27           1
#> 28           1
#> 29           1
#> 30           1
#> 31           1
#> 32           1
#> 33           1
#> 34           1
#> 35           1
#> 36           1
#> 37           1
#> 38           1
#> 39           1
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0
vcov(dr.al)
#>                   silt:(Intercept)    silt:depth clay:(Intercept)    clay:depth
#> silt:(Intercept)      0.0473798364 -1.050769e-03     0.0326233405 -8.299412e-04
#> silt:depth           -0.0010507691  3.074723e-05    -0.0008572637  2.678223e-05
#> clay:(Intercept)      0.0326233405 -8.572637e-04     0.0633941586 -1.286624e-03
#> clay:depth           -0.0008299412  2.678223e-05    -0.0012866239  3.464041e-05
#> (phi):(Intercept)    -0.0078150334  3.083413e-04    -0.0123548759  3.658234e-04
#>                   (phi):(Intercept)
#> silt:(Intercept)      -0.0078150334
#> silt:depth             0.0003083413
#> clay:(Intercept)      -0.0123548759
#> clay:depth             0.0003658234
#> (phi):(Intercept)      0.0263310676

#### Predicted values can be obtained manually
pred.al <- cbind(rep(0, nrow(lake.data)), model.matrix(dr.al)[["X"]][[2]] %*% coef(dr.al)[[1]][[2]], model.matrix(dr.al)[["X"]][[3]] %*% coef(dr.al)[[1]][[3]])

cbind(exp(pred.al)/rowSums(exp(pred.al)), predict(dr.al))
#>                                         sand      silt      clay
#> 1  0.54564230 0.3537594 0.1005983 0.54564230 0.3537594 0.1005983
#> 2  0.53173238 0.3627984 0.1054692 0.53173238 0.3627984 0.1054692
#> 3  0.51990640 0.3703894 0.1097042 0.51990640 0.3703894 0.1097042
#> 4  0.51775179 0.3717629 0.1104853 0.51775179 0.3717629 0.1104853
#> 5  0.48858251 0.3900609 0.1213566 0.48858251 0.3900609 0.1213566
#> 6  0.48209121 0.3940552 0.1238536 0.48209121 0.3940552 0.1238536
#> 7  0.46371369 0.4052026 0.1310837 0.46371369 0.4052026 0.1310837
#> 8  0.45616113 0.4097128 0.1341261 0.45616113 0.4097128 0.1341261
#> 9  0.43466911 0.4223098 0.1430211 0.43466911 0.4223098 0.1430211
#> 10 0.41973317 0.4308474 0.1494194 0.41973317 0.4308474 0.1494194
#> 11 0.41654729 0.4326445 0.1508082 0.41654729 0.4326445 0.1508082
#> 12 0.39546722 0.4443124 0.1602203 0.39546722 0.4443124 0.1602203
#> 13 0.38090272 0.4521368 0.1669605 0.38090272 0.4521368 0.1669605
#> 14 0.31415023 0.4851382 0.2007116 0.31415023 0.4851382 0.2007116
#> 15 0.30375427 0.4897919 0.2064538 0.30375427 0.4897919 0.2064538
#> 16 0.27456954 0.5020181 0.2234123 0.27456954 0.5020181 0.2234123
#> 17 0.26579013 0.5054305 0.2287794 0.26579013 0.5054305 0.2287794
#> 18 0.27368408 0.5023682 0.2239477 0.27368408 0.5023682 0.2239477
#> 19 0.22921546 0.5180969 0.2526876 0.22921546 0.5180969 0.2526876
#> 20 0.19330379 0.5275628 0.2791334 0.19330379 0.5275628 0.2791334
#> 21 0.19260078 0.5277126 0.2796867 0.19260078 0.5277126 0.2796867
#> 22 0.18362968 0.5294860 0.2868843 0.18362968 0.5294860 0.2868843
#> 23 0.17694075 0.5306340 0.2924253 0.17694075 0.5306340 0.2924253
#> 24 0.17628196 0.5307385 0.2929795 0.17628196 0.5307385 0.2929795
#> 25 0.12085487 0.5325691 0.3465760 0.12085487 0.5325691 0.3465760
#> 26 0.11652562 0.5319652 0.3515092 0.11652562 0.5319652 0.3515092
#> 27 0.10914794 0.5305988 0.3602533 0.10914794 0.5305988 0.3602533
#> 28 0.10604578 0.5298867 0.3640676 0.10604578 0.5298867 0.3640676
#> 29 0.07928539 0.5194768 0.4012378 0.07928539 0.5194768 0.4012378
#> 30 0.06577906 0.5102695 0.4239514 0.06577906 0.5102695 0.4239514
#> 31 0.06350589 0.5083589 0.4281352 0.06350589 0.5083589 0.4281352
#> 32 0.05292889 0.4977107 0.4493604 0.05292889 0.4977107 0.4493604
#> 33 0.04338308 0.4848967 0.4717203 0.04338308 0.4848967 0.4717203
#> 34 0.03479652 0.4696035 0.4956000 0.03479652 0.4696035 0.4956000
#> 35 0.03415744 0.4682773 0.4975653 0.03415744 0.4682773 0.4975653
#> 36 0.03069033 0.4605185 0.5087912 0.03069033 0.4605185 0.5087912
#> 37 0.03040494 0.4598337 0.5097613 0.03040494 0.4598337 0.5097613
#> 38 0.02174826 0.4346861 0.5435656 0.02174826 0.4346861 0.5435656
#> 39 0.01630737 0.4125423 0.5711503 0.01630737 0.4125423 0.5711503

## But no idea on standard errors


# Common parametrization
dr.co <- DirichReg(lake.data ~ depth, ArcticLake, model = "common")
summary(dr.co)
#> Call:
#> DirichReg(formula = lake.data ~ depth, data = ArcticLake, model = "common")
#> 
#> Standardized Residuals:
#>           Min       1Q   Median      3Q     Max
#> sand  -1.7724  -0.8319   0.0120  1.3435  2.2862
#> silt  -1.0863  -0.5343  -0.1279  0.2892  1.4493
#> clay  -2.0868  -0.7516  -0.0012  0.4391  1.9660
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Beta-Coefficients for variable no. 1: sand
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
#> (Intercept) 0.116625   0.409292   0.285  0.77569   
#> depth       0.023351   0.007454   3.133  0.00173 **
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Beta-Coefficients for variable no. 2: silt
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -0.310596   0.344731  -0.901    0.368    
#> depth        0.055567   0.006365   8.730   <2e-16 ***
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Beta-Coefficients for variable no. 3: clay
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -1.151956   0.298473   -3.86 0.000114 ***
#> depth        0.064302   0.005738   11.21  < 2e-16 ***
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Significance codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Log-likelihood: 101.4 on 6 df (100 BFGS + 1 NR Iterations)
#> AIC: -190.7, BIC: -180.8
#> Number of Observations: 39
#> Link: Log
#> Parametrization: common
model.matrix(dr.co)
#> $X
#> $X[[1]]
#>    (Intercept) depth
#> 1            1  10.4
#> 2            1  11.7
#> 3            1  12.8
#> 4            1  13.0
#> 5            1  15.7
#> 6            1  16.3
#> 7            1  18.0
#> 8            1  18.7
#> 9            1  20.7
#> 10           1  22.1
#> 11           1  22.4
#> 12           1  24.4
#> 13           1  25.8
#> 14           1  32.5
#> 15           1  33.6
#> 16           1  36.8
#> 17           1  37.8
#> 18           1  36.9
#> 19           1  42.2
#> 20           1  47.0
#> 21           1  47.1
#> 22           1  48.4
#> 23           1  49.4
#> 24           1  49.5
#> 25           1  59.2
#> 26           1  60.1
#> 27           1  61.7
#> 28           1  62.4
#> 29           1  69.3
#> 30           1  73.6
#> 31           1  74.4
#> 32           1  78.5
#> 33           1  82.9
#> 34           1  87.7
#> 35           1  88.1
#> 36           1  90.4
#> 37           1  90.6
#> 38           1  97.7
#> 39           1 103.7
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> $X[[2]]
#>    (Intercept) depth
#> 1            1  10.4
#> 2            1  11.7
#> 3            1  12.8
#> 4            1  13.0
#> 5            1  15.7
#> 6            1  16.3
#> 7            1  18.0
#> 8            1  18.7
#> 9            1  20.7
#> 10           1  22.1
#> 11           1  22.4
#> 12           1  24.4
#> 13           1  25.8
#> 14           1  32.5
#> 15           1  33.6
#> 16           1  36.8
#> 17           1  37.8
#> 18           1  36.9
#> 19           1  42.2
#> 20           1  47.0
#> 21           1  47.1
#> 22           1  48.4
#> 23           1  49.4
#> 24           1  49.5
#> 25           1  59.2
#> 26           1  60.1
#> 27           1  61.7
#> 28           1  62.4
#> 29           1  69.3
#> 30           1  73.6
#> 31           1  74.4
#> 32           1  78.5
#> 33           1  82.9
#> 34           1  87.7
#> 35           1  88.1
#> 36           1  90.4
#> 37           1  90.6
#> 38           1  97.7
#> 39           1 103.7
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> $X[[3]]
#>    (Intercept) depth
#> 1            1  10.4
#> 2            1  11.7
#> 3            1  12.8
#> 4            1  13.0
#> 5            1  15.7
#> 6            1  16.3
#> 7            1  18.0
#> 8            1  18.7
#> 9            1  20.7
#> 10           1  22.1
#> 11           1  22.4
#> 12           1  24.4
#> 13           1  25.8
#> 14           1  32.5
#> 15           1  33.6
#> 16           1  36.8
#> 17           1  37.8
#> 18           1  36.9
#> 19           1  42.2
#> 20           1  47.0
#> 21           1  47.1
#> 22           1  48.4
#> 23           1  49.4
#> 24           1  49.5
#> 25           1  59.2
#> 26           1  60.1
#> 27           1  61.7
#> 28           1  62.4
#> 29           1  69.3
#> 30           1  73.6
#> 31           1  74.4
#> 32           1  78.5
#> 33           1  82.9
#> 34           1  87.7
#> 35           1  88.1
#> 36           1  90.4
#> 37           1  90.6
#> 38           1  97.7
#> 39           1 103.7
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> 
#> $Z
#> NULL
vcov(dr.co)
#>                  sand:(Intercept)    sand:depth silt:(Intercept)    silt:depth
#> sand:(Intercept)      0.167519795 -2.799915e-03      0.113137565 -2.041207e-03
#> sand:depth           -0.002799915  5.556085e-05     -0.001919728  4.238757e-05
#> silt:(Intercept)      0.113137565 -1.919728e-03      0.118839725 -1.937139e-03
#> silt:depth           -0.002041207  4.238757e-05     -0.001937139  4.051702e-05
#> clay:(Intercept)      0.090971168 -1.502635e-03      0.085053999 -1.398705e-03
#> clay:depth           -0.001786148  3.755954e-05     -0.001551214  3.422012e-05
#>                  clay:(Intercept)    clay:depth
#> sand:(Intercept)      0.090971168 -1.786148e-03
#> sand:depth           -0.001502635  3.755954e-05
#> silt:(Intercept)      0.085053999 -1.551214e-03
#> silt:depth           -0.001398705  3.422012e-05
#> clay:(Intercept)      0.089085995 -1.438300e-03
#> clay:depth           -0.001438300  3.292671e-05

#### Predicted values can be obtained manually
pred.co <- cbind(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[1]] %*% coef(dr.co)[[1]], model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[2]] %*% coef(dr.co)[[2]], model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[3]] %*% coef(dr.co)[[3]])

cbind(exp(pred.co)/rowSums(exp(pred.co)), predict(dr.co))
#>                                         sand      silt      clay
#> 1  0.42689474 0.3893063 0.1837990 0.42689474 0.3893063 0.1837990
#> 2  0.41579279 0.3953997 0.1888075 0.41579279 0.3953997 0.1888075
#> 3  0.40645934 0.4004672 0.1930734 0.40645934 0.4004672 0.1930734
#> 4  0.40476885 0.4013796 0.1938516 0.40476885 0.4013796 0.1938516
#> 5  0.38216732 0.4134075 0.2044251 0.38216732 0.4134075 0.2044251
#> 6  0.37720562 0.4160043 0.2067901 0.37720562 0.4160043 0.2067901
#> 7  0.36328179 0.4232029 0.2135153 0.36328179 0.4232029 0.2135153
#> 8  0.35760963 0.4260967 0.2162937 0.35760963 0.4260967 0.2162937
#> 9  0.34161564 0.4341296 0.2242547 0.34161564 0.4341296 0.2242547
#> 10 0.33061887 0.4395388 0.2298423 0.33061887 0.4395388 0.2298423
#> 11 0.32828484 0.4406744 0.2310407 0.32828484 0.4406744 0.2310407
#> 12 0.31293610 0.4480283 0.2390356 0.31293610 0.4480283 0.2390356
#> 13 0.30241960 0.4529472 0.2446332 0.30241960 0.4529472 0.2446332
#> 14 0.25491542 0.4737791 0.2713055 0.25491542 0.4737791 0.2713055
#> 15 0.24758892 0.4767619 0.2756492 0.24758892 0.4767619 0.2756492
#> 16 0.22706904 0.4847308 0.2882002 0.22706904 0.4847308 0.2882002
#> 17 0.22090202 0.4870053 0.2920926 0.22090202 0.4870053 0.2920926
#> 18 0.22644704 0.4849629 0.2885901 0.22644704 0.4849629 0.2885901
#> 19 0.19517141 0.4958065 0.3090221 0.19517141 0.4958065 0.3090221
#> 20 0.16970839 0.5032200 0.3270716 0.16970839 0.5032200 0.3270716
#> 21 0.16920654 0.5033509 0.3274425 0.16920654 0.5033509 0.3274425
#> 22 0.16278740 0.5049674 0.3322452 0.16278740 0.5049674 0.3322452
#> 23 0.15798143 0.5061042 0.3359144 0.15798143 0.5061042 0.3359144
#> 24 0.15750709 0.5062128 0.3362801 0.15750709 0.5062128 0.3362801
#> 25 0.11669825 0.5126413 0.3706604 0.11669825 0.5126413 0.3706604
#> 26 0.11340968 0.5128515 0.3737388 0.11340968 0.5128515 0.3737388
#> 27 0.10775918 0.5130763 0.3791645 0.10775918 0.5130763 0.3791645
#> 28 0.10536443 0.5131161 0.3815194 0.10536443 0.5131161 0.3815194
#> 29 0.08413624 0.5117351 0.4041287 0.08413624 0.5117351 0.4041287
#> 30 0.07291797 0.5094007 0.4176813 0.07291797 0.5094007 0.4176813
#> 31 0.07098647 0.5088545 0.4201590 0.07098647 0.5088545 0.4201590
#> 32 0.06179907 0.5055506 0.4326503 0.06179907 0.5055506 0.4326503
#> 33 0.05316455 0.5011489 0.4456866 0.05316455 0.5011489 0.4456866
#> 34 0.04503110 0.4954682 0.4595007 0.04503110 0.4954682 0.4595007
#> 35 0.04440872 0.4949576 0.4606337 0.04440872 0.4949576 0.4606337
#> 36 0.04098400 0.4919197 0.4670963 0.04098400 0.4919197 0.4670963
#> 37 0.04069825 0.4916476 0.4676541 0.04069825 0.4916476 0.4676541
#> 38 0.03169254 0.4812536 0.4870538 0.03169254 0.4812536 0.4870538
#> 39 0.02559402 0.4715239 0.5028821 0.02559402 0.4715239 0.5028821

### This code replicates would work in models with a single response (i've tried a linear model and a beta regression). I am not sure whether this approach is valid here
sqrt(  diag(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[1]] %*% vcov(dr.co)[1:2, 1:2] %*% t(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[1]]))  )
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 0.3395453 0.3310703 0.3239523 0.3226636 0.3054467 0.3016696 0.2910749 0.2867613 
#>         9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
#> 0.2746099 0.2662706 0.2645030 0.2529084 0.2450055 0.2102653 0.2051621 0.1915432 
#>        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24 
#> 0.1877067 0.1911499 0.1736432 0.1645045 0.1643915 0.1632258 0.1627166 0.1626844 
#>        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32 
#> 0.1753016 0.1779224 0.1830966 0.1855560 0.2151326 0.2373673 0.2417474 0.2651660 
#>        33        34        35        36        37        38        39 
#> 0.2917719 0.3221015 0.3246790 0.3396283 0.3409380 0.3882794 0.4293037
sqrt(  diag(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[2]] %*% vcov(dr.co)[3:4, 3:4] %*% t(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[2]]))  )
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 0.2879749 0.2811708 0.2754764 0.2744476 0.2607692 0.2577866 0.2494599 0.2460876 
#>         9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
#> 0.2366501 0.2302327 0.2288792 0.2200671 0.2141333 0.1890020 0.1854887 0.1764540 
#>        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24 
#> 0.1740239 0.1762022 0.1658297 0.1620207 0.1620017 0.1619820 0.1622543 0.1622952 
#>        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32 
#> 0.1774260 0.1798428 0.1845008 0.1866769 0.2119782 0.2305903 0.2342427 0.2537417 
#>        33        34        35        36        37        38        39 
#> 0.2758833 0.3011538 0.3033036 0.3157792 0.3168727 0.3564679 0.3908765
sqrt(  diag(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[3]] %*% vcov(dr.co)[5:6, 5:6] %*% t(model.matrix(dr.co)[["X"]][[3]]))  )
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 0.2504610 0.2448206 0.2401254 0.2392798 0.2281216 0.2257116 0.2190330 0.2163509 
#>         9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
#> 0.2089238 0.2039482 0.2029075 0.1962147 0.1917995 0.1742852 0.1720615 0.1667866 
#>        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24 
#> 0.1655219 0.1666517 0.1622673 0.1631591 0.1632270 0.1642904 0.1653329 0.1654477 
#>        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32 
#> 0.1848987 0.1874405 0.1922190 0.1944090 0.2187871 0.2360739 0.2394330 0.2572460 
#>        33        34        35        36        37        38        39 
#> 0.2773116 0.3000951 0.3020295 0.3132470 0.3142297 0.3497673 0.3806129

Created on 2024-08-22 with reprex v2.0.2

Standard errors around predictions can be obtained through simulation following the approach of Douma and Weedon 2019 (https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.13234), in Appendix S4. However, I'm not submitting this as an answer, as I wonder whether SEs could be obtainted through matrix algebra jut like the predictions
